# Signed Java Applet is not running

Tags: java, applet, code-signing

After creating an applet and signing it, it is still not running. Not even a warning is being presented, the app is just blocked.

Unfortunately, the error message is not very helpful as to why exactly the app is being blocked.

My app manifest follows. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: App Name
Implementation-Version: 0.1.0
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: My App Name
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.7.0_51
Main-Class: my.app.main.MyApp
Codebase: *
```

The error message is below:

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@4d89136d
basic: tap installed
basic: Creating PluginEmbeddedFrame served by com.apple.java.jrs.carenderserver-74486
basic: Done creating PluginEmbeddedFrame
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@74108172
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar
network: Connecting http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8000/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8000/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar 
network: ResponseCode for http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar : 200
network: Encoding for http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar : null
network: Server response: (length: 846276, lastModified: Sun Mar 30 18:58:56 CEST 2014, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/java-archive)
network: Downloading resource: http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar
    Content-Length: 846,276
    Content-Encoding: null
network: Wrote URL http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar to File /var/folders/vy/8gzkm2vj3w72v56yhs6wnmcm0000gn/T/jar_cache7229428729716294985.tmp
security: Blacklist revocation check is enabled
security: blacklist: created: NEED_LOAD, lastModified: 1395943667000
security: blacklist: check contains 3KbI9px7RHQA4LRm4Mhesfkw/pMu7Kv9Lyyv+JWic38=, state now NEED_LOAD
security: blacklist: loadCache
security: blacklist: not  found in cache
security: Trusted libraries list check is enabled
security: Trusted libraries list file not found
security: blacklist: check contains 3KbI9px7RHQA4LRm4Mhesfkw/pMu7Kv9Lyyv+JWic38=, state now IN_MEMORY
security: blacklist: not  found in cache
network: Disconnect connection to http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar
network: Downloaded http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar: /var/folders/vy/8gzkm2vj3w72v56yhs6wnmcm0000gn/T/jar_cache7229428729716294985.tmp
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://localhost:8000/build/distributions/my-app-0.1.0-shadow.jar
security: Accessing keys and certificate in Mozilla user profile: null
security: Loading Deployment certificates from /Users/thomas/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/security/trusted.certs
security: Loaded Deployment certificates from /Users/thomas/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/security/trusted.certs
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loading certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Loaded certificates from Deployment session certificate store
security: Validate the certificate chain using CertPath API
security: Loading Root CA certificates from /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
security: Loaded Root CA certificates from /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Obtain certificate collection in Root CA certificate store
security: Loading blacklisted.certs file: /Users/thomas/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/security/blacklisted.certs
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: F8D741A17228FC944EC377198DC2004640F9A9F8D0B449D451EA234DA2062935
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 09ED6E991FC3273D8FEA317D339C02041861973549CFA6E1558F411F11211AA3
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: C3846BF24B9E93CA64274C0EC67C1ECC5E024FFCACD2D74019350E81FE546AE4
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: The CRL support is enabled
network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: OCSP Response: GOOD
network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://ocsp.godaddy.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
security: OCSP Response: GOOD
security: Certificate validation succeeded using OCSP/CRL
basic: Your security settings have blocked a signed application from running
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: exception: Your security settings have blocked a signed application from running.
com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked a signed application from running
    at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.showBlockedDialog(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.askUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Ignored exception: com.sun.deploy.security.BlockedException: Your security settings have blocked a signed application from running
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@74108172
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out: one has to allow "all-permission" in the Java configuration before it can be requested by an applet.

[image]